# Directly upload files to my own Google Drive using Google Drive PHP SDK

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload files to my own Google Drive (not the end user's Google Drive) when an end user uploads their CV to my web server.

Once the user uploads a file to my server, I want to upload this file to my own Google Drive (on the server-side) using PHP. Is this possible?

I set up all secret keys and service accounts for this as described in the documentation, but can't get it to work.

Comment: Would you mind sharing some code with us?

Comment: You need to go into detail about what you've set up, and why you think it should be working. Code you've written, logs that show what is being processed, etc.